# Documentation for failures in nightwatch

Tags: node.js, jenkins, junit

I am running the nightwatch tests and want to separate out failures based on whether they are

- actual bugs
- flaky tests
- failures
- success

I want to document this in junit reporting system that nightwatch has as I use the junit report to create a report in Jenkins. Does anyone know of a system that will allow me to do that? Or how I can go about changing the framework to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate those test with different tag names.

```
module.exports = {
  '@tags' : ['bugs'],
```

So you can treat them seperatetly in jenkins running different jobs for them, for instance.